# What is the average number of views per question?

Tags: discussion, views

I'm wondering what the average number of views for a question is over the entirety of Stack Exchange.

Knowing this would give me an idea of how '*difficult*' getting **10,000** views really is, depending on whether the average number of views is (guessing), **350**, or **3,000**.

**Edit:**
Either a way to test the entire Stack Exchange network, or rather a method to check the statistics for any individual site would make the answer acceptable.

Also, *views* is meant as the number that is displayed with the question, not by page loads or any other ways to count a "view".

Comment: An average over the whole network isn't going to be much use to you. An average at a site you're active on and want the badge on would be more useful for your purposes. I think you can figure that from the SEDE, but I'm not entirely sure. (I don't play with it much.)

Comment: @Kendra, good point, I think a network average would be interesting though. A way to test each individual site, or a combination of sites would make a great answer. By the way, what's *SEDE*?

Comment: [Stack Exchange Data Explorer.](http://data.stackexchange.com/) It's a SQL database with data about the sites and posts on them that users can query.

Comment: Just know that [this](http://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/could-a-paradox-kill-an-ai) was the first question with 2,500 views on the site, and the first with more than 25 votes (and the second with that many).

Comment: That was the first gold badge on the site... :P

Comment: @Mithrandir I'm glad my question was so well accepted on SE.AI. It's actually my second 10,000+ question, but I think it's the one I'm the most proud of :)

Comment: The average on AI appears to be... 41, according to the query below.

Comment: @Mithrandir I'd be curious to see if it goes up after the database refreshes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/532686) gets those results for you across all sites:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , postid nvarchar(35)
                       , viewcount bigint);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , p.id
     , p.viewcount
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts p 
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

--print @sql

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select 'Network wide'
      , count(*) as cnt
      , sum (viewcount) as [sum]
      , avg(viewcount) as [avg]
from #results
union
select site
      , count(*) as cnt
      , sum (viewcount) as [sum]
      , avg(viewcount) as [avg]
from #results
group by site
order by 2 desc
    
drop table #results
```

When run today this is what the result looks like:

[image: result of viewcount and average per site and network wide]

When you run the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/532686) yourself to see the full result or you can download the CSV result by clicking the link at the right hand side of the result.

Keep in mind that [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is only updated once a week, in the weekend.

Comment: Could you post the entire list, or is it too long?

Comment: Oh, I see, you just have to click the link :P

Comment: @JoshB. yes, and you can fork the query and make changes if you want. It is all open

Comment: A fast response and a great answer. Thanks!